# ASP.NET Razor and table from SqlConnection

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have an existing `SqlConnection conn;` in some controller (using `ASP.NET MVC3 + Razor`). Now, I would like to render a simple table depending on some SQL command.

**The question is:**
How to "bind" loaded data in Razor using `ViewBag`? Is it necessary to iterate row-after-row and produce `<tr>....</tr>` in Razor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no binding like this. And a simple for loop means it isnt much code either, example...

```
<table>
@foreach(var row in Model.MyRows)
{
   <tr>
      @foreach(var col in row.Columns)
      {
         <td>@(col.Value)</td>
      }
   </tr>
}
</table>
```

hope that gives you an idea anyway, and this way you get a lot more control over the style of your rendered table

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest you to use strongly typed views and pass a populated model to your view and as you mentioned, iterate items of the ViewModel. Binding doesn't really have a place in MVC.